# "Rect argument is invalid"

Tags: python, error-handling, pygame

I have been trying to code a game and it keeps giving me a `"rect argument is invalid"` error. If anybody could please tell me what I'm doing wrong here that would be great. I believe it has to do with lists and tuples in the code, but I've reviewed it thoroughly and it just won't function correctly. The code just keeps showing me the same error message.

My code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

pygame.init()

Width = 800
Height = 600

Red = (255, 0, 0)
Blue = (0, 0, 255)
White = (255, 255, 255)
backgroundColor = (0, 0, 0)

playerSize = 50
playerPos = [100, 300]

columnSize = [50, 150]
columnPos1 = [700, random.randint(0,random.randint(0,100))]
columnPos2 = [700, random.randint(0,random.randint(400,500))]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Height))

game_over = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not game_over:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            x = playerPos[0]
            y = playerPos[1]

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= 20
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += 20
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y -= 20
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y += 20
            
            playerPos = [x,y]

    screen.fill(backgroundColor)
    if columnPos1[0] >= 0 and columnPos1[0] < Width and columnPos2[0] >= 0 and columnPos2[0] < Width:
        columnPos1[0] -= 10
        columnPos2[0] -= 10
    else:
        columnPos1[0] = 700
        columnPos2[0] = 700

        columnPos1[1] = [700, random.randint(0,random.randint(0,100))]
        columnPos2[1] = [700, random.randint(0,random.randint(400,500))]

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Red, (playerPos[0], playerPos[1], playerSize, playerSize))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Red, (columnPos1[0], columnPos1[1], columnSize[0], columnSize[1])) #this is where rect is invalid
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Red, (columnPos2[0], columnPos2[1], columnSize[0], columnSize[1])) #here as well

    clock.tick(30)

    pygame.display.update()
```

The error started happening once I added

```
columnPos1[1] = [700, random.randint(0,random.randint(0,100))]
columnPos2[1] = [700, random.randint(0,random.randint(400,500))]
```

Answer (score 0):

`columnSize` is `[50, 150]`, so your rect argument looks like

```
(columnPos1[0], columnPos1[1], [50, 150], [50, 150])
```

You probably meant

```
(columnPos1[0], columnPos1[1], columnSize[0], columnSize[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I fixed the issue:

instead of this:

```
columnPos1[1] = [700, random.randint(0,random.randint(0,100))]
columnPos2[1] = [700, random.randint(0,random.randint(400,500))]
```

I should've done this:

```
columnPos1[1] = random.randint(0,random.randint(0,100))
columnPos2[1] = random.randint(0,random.randint(400,500))
```